# Change string using JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, substring, trim

I have this JS

```
var link ="#step-2";
```

What i need is to get new string that will be like this

```
var newlink = "STEP 2";
```

I hope this is simple solution using jquery?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `trim`ming.

Comment: [trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) is something completely different

Comment: you want to remove only hash & hyphen or want remove all special characters?

Comment: As you've changed in your question title, changing characters will be enough here. So you should use `replace()` method to change the characters you don't want into characters you want to see. You can either do this by a simple replace or regular expresssion replace.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to trim (`trim()`, and `$.trim()`, removes the leading, and trailing, white-space from a string, not special, or otherwise-identified, characters) the string; you need, instead, to use `replace()`:

```
var link ="#step-2",
    newlink = link.toUpperCase().replace(/[#-]/g, function (a){
        return a === '#' ? '' : ' ';
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var link ="#step-2";
var newlink = link.replace('#', '').replace('-', ' ').toUpperCase();
```